# round() in Python doesn't round when applied to the variable but does when applied to the value assigned to the variable?

Tags: python, rounding

Why does the round function work for the variables 'interest' and 'mortgase' in the first code below and not the second? I have looked for the answer, but none of the post I found gives me a fit explanation.

Thanks in advance!

Working round() code:

```
#generate monthly outstanding mortgage

#Input: annual interest rate, a floating-point percentage
rate = 0.05

# Input: monthly payment, a positive integer in a currency
payment = 200

#Input/Output: mortgage, a positive number, same currency
mortgage = 1000

remMortgage = []
remMortgage = remMortgage + [mortgage]

print('Outstanding mortgange: ', mortgage)
while not (mortgage == 0 or mortgage < payment):
    interest = round (mortgage * rate / 12,1)
    mortgage = round (mortgage + interest - payment,1)
    remMortgage = remMortgage + [mortgage]
print ('Outstanding mortgange: ', remMortgage)
```

Non Working round() code:

```
#generate monthly outstanding mortgage

#Input: annual interest rate, a floating-point percentage
rate = 0.05

# Input: monthly payment, a positive integer in a currency
payment = 200

#Input/Output: mortgage, a positive number, same currency
mortgage = 1000

remMortgage = []
remMortgage = remMortgage + [mortgage]

print('Outstanding mortgange: ', mortgage)
while not (mortgage == 0 or mortgage < payment):
    interest = mortgage * rate / 12
    round (interest,1)
    mortgage = mortgage + interest - payment
    round (mortgage,1)
    remMortgage = remMortgage + [mortgage]
print ('Outstanding mortgange: ', remMortgage)
```

Comment: `int` and `float` values are *immutable*, [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) returns a new instance.

Comment: The `round()` function doesn't modify the object you pass to it as an argument in place - instead it returns the rounded value for you to assign as you see fit. In this case, `int`s and `float`s are immutable, so that's the only way it could work, but it's pretty common for Python functions to return new objects rather than modifying them in place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the variable. Round is working otherwise in both the scenarios I believe.

Answer (score 0):

The `round()` function returns the rounded value. It does not change the value you inserted as a parameter.

Although there is a function in the integer class itself, `__round()__` which does change the parent value.

Answer (score 0):

Round is a function that returns a value. It doesnt change the value you put in, instead creates a new value inside its code, being the rounded number, and returns this. When you write  `interest = round (mortgage * rate / 12,1)` you are assigning the returned value to this variable. When you just call it like `round (interest,1)` it still returns a value but you are not doing anything with that value. And since the function doesnt change any existing value, this gives you nothing.